# Someone who prefers no cussing around them

Tags: single-word-requests

Extra points if the word implies that the person in question is pious.

Comment: Do you have a context?

Comment: "**Mother**" or "**girlfriend**" will do.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you can award extra points.

Comment: Is this the same, or different, for a word you use do describe someone who prefers no racist language around him/her?

Comment: Or how about: someone who prefers no non-grammatical English around him/her?

Comment: I apologize for the vague question. I'm referring to one who unconditionally refuses to be near those who cuss for religious reasons (ie, using the Lord's name in vain).

Comment: *I* usually cuss for profane reasons, not religious ones - would your friend find me an acceptable companion?

Answer (score 5):

prim

"puritanical" or “straight-laced”

“prig” or “prudish” may be taken as pejorative; if that is what you intend.  (Although your own term “pious” may work nicely.) - http://thesaurus.com/browse/prudish

Also – “stuffy”, or “prissy”

To someone’s face you might use “moderate”, “reserved”, or even “appropriate”, as I think most people believe *appropriate* language is simply language with no cussing or off-color remarks, used for large audiences and *moderate* minds.

Also – sensible, restrained, measured

Or - **goody two-shoes**! - http://thesaurus.com/browse/goody+two-shoes

Or perhaps “Ned Flanders”...

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use *prude,* never mind the context.

Comment: PRUDE: *a person who is or claims to be easily shocked by matters relating to sex or nudity.*  Actually, that is not what I thought of when the OP said *cussing*